# How to add predictors to LSTM time series model?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, supervised-learning, lstm

I'm doing Long-Short-Term-Memory (LSTM) to forecast time series. I was wondering, could we add x-reg part to an LSTM model? Like adding an X-Reg part to and ARIMA model?

Say I have a response monthly time series y (for about 10~20 years observation). And say I have about 400 signals (predictor time series).
Should I do feature-selection and regression first and then use LSTM to model the residuals?

Or is this the wrong way to add predictors to LSTM?

Thank you!

Comment: You can just add them as additional inputs to your LSTM. It's actually much more straightforward than with ARIMA or ETS.

Comment: Hi Alex, Could you give an example on how to add xreg to LSTM? if my "dim(y_train_arr)" is [105,1], and I have 2 predictors, what should my "dim(x_train_arr)" be? [105,3,1] or [105,1,3]?

Comment: That will depend on what too you are using for LSTM.